# How to get system time in UTC format using chrono

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am trying to find the system time in UTC format using the chrono. I think the following program only gives me local time , please can some one help me out ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>  

auto GetSystemTime() -> uint8_t * {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(std::ctime(&currentTime));
}

int main()
{

   std::cout << GetSystemTime();
    
}
```

Comment: Working with dates and times is a real bother.  If you can't use C++20, I would suggest using Howard Hinnant's [Date and Time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck with C++11 - C++17, you could use [`std::gmtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime) which "*converts given time since epoch as `std::time_t` value into calendar time, expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)*" and then [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) to format it the way you want.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

std::string GetSystemTime() {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    std::ostringstream os;
    os << std::put_time(gmtime(&currentTime), "%F %T");

    return os.str();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/he9nn3)

Note about `std::gmtime`: This function may not be thread-safe.

Comment: But beware of thread unsafety of `gmtime`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you can use this [free, open-source, header-only preview of C++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) with c++11/14/17:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

auto
GetSystemTime()
{
    return date::format("%F %T %Z", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << GetSystemTime() << '\n';
}
```

Using:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -I../date/include
```

this just output for me:

```
2021-03-10 21:49:51.861588 UTC
```

You can format this however you want using [these formatting flags](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#to_stream_formatting).

Comment: I'm glad you answered this.  Your library is very appreciated, +1